# Large file crashes VSCode

Tags: file, visual-studio-code, crash, large-files

I have a very large file (1gb Approx) I made as a small test, problem is, VSCode crashes when launching now, since it keeps opening the file, and I am unable to close the window.

Any path, any folder, any file. It will always first open the `array.txt` file that even after being deleted still persists (I guess cached?)

Anyhow, It completely broke my VSCode and now I cannot launch it without crashing.

What can I do so it stops opening it? I've tried reinstalling VSCode but its no avail.

Comment: VScode will pump up my computer resources to 100%

SSD, Ram and CPU all 100% when launching due to the file trying to be opened..

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me(and took less than 5 minutes) was backing up my personal settings, uninstalling VSCode with Winget and deleting the whole `\appdata\roaming\code` folder.
Upon reopening VSCode, the file was gone.
**Be aware that data will be lost, other workspaces, editor history, etc.**

I came across the same problem with a 900mb large SQL dump I accidentally opened. Tried deleting workspace folders, editing vsdb files, deleting and renaming the file, deleting cache folders, that same particular file would **ALWAYS** pop back up in the workspace even when all the other files from the previous state were gone, it just kept popping up. Until a better solution is presented, i'd recommend reinstalling VSCode right off the bat.